# Spark sequences [int] comparison with [String] sequence ouput

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, udf

I was trying to compare integer wrapped arrays in two different columns and give the ratings as string:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
```

The DataFrame data has column A and B with wrapped array I would like to compare:

```
val data = Seq(
    (Seq(1,2,3),Seq(4,5,6),Seq(7,8,9)),
    (Seq(1,1,3),Seq(6,5,7),Seq(11,9,8))
    ).toDF("A","B","C")
```

And here is how it looks like:

```
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: array<int>, B: array<int> ... 1 more field]
+---------+---------+----------+
|        A|        B|         C|
+---------+---------+----------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[4, 5, 6]| [7, 8, 9]|
|[1, 1, 3]|[6, 5, 7]|[11, 9, 8]|
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Then here is the the user define function which I would like to compare each elements in paired arrays in column A and B per row and give the ratings with simple logics. For example if A(1) > B(1) then D(1) is "Top". So as first row with column D, I hope to have ["Top", "Top", "Top"]

```
def myToChar(num1: Seq[Int], num2: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
        val twozipped = num1.zip(num2)
        for ((x,y) <- num1.zip(num2)) {
          if (x > y)  "Top"
          if (x < y)  "Well"
          if (x == y)  "Good"
    }}


val udfToChar = udf(myToChar(_: Seq[Int], _: Seq[Int]))

val ouput = data.withColumn("D",udfToChar($"A",$"B"))
```

However, I kept getting the `<console>:45: error: type mismatch;` error information. Not sure if my udf() type definition is wrong and appreciate any guidance to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your `myToChar` definition is declared to return a `Seq[String]` - but its implementation doesn't - it returns `Unit`, because a `for` expression (without a `yield` clause) has `Unit` type.

You can fix this by fixing the implementation of the function:

- Replace the `for` with a `map` operation
- Replace the last `if` with an `else`, otherwise the mapping function also returns `Unit` for inputs that adhere to none of the if conditions (unlike with pattern matching, the compiler can't conclude that your if conditions are exhaustive - it must assume there's also a possibility none of them would hold true)

So - a correct implementation would be:

```
def myToChar(num1: Seq[Int], num2: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
  num1.zip(num2).map { case (x, y) =>
    if (x > y) "Top"
    if (x < y) "Well"
    else "Good"
  }
}
```

Or alternatively using pattern matching with guards:

```
def myToChar(num1: Seq[Int], num2: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
  num1.zip(num2).map {
    case (x, y) if x > y => "Top"
    case (x, y) if x < y => "Well"
    case _ => "Good"
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer indeed. May I learn from you the difference between `num1.zip(num2).foreach()` versus `num1.zip(num2).map()`? My silly thinking is that `foreach()` will loop through each element ...

Comment: `map` expects a function that _transforms_ each element into a new one (possibly of a different type) and therefore returns a new sequence with the transformed elements; `foreach` expects a function that _operates_ on each element and does not return a value (technically, returns `Unit`), and therefore the `foreach` expression itself does _not_ return a value (again - `Unit`). `foreach` is therefore useful when you want to cause some "side-effect" (e.g. write to log, persist to disk, send over network etc.) while `map` is useful when you want to return a value.